# CSS: select element preceded by a sibling element

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have something similar to the following:

```
<ul id="list-cats">
   <li><img src="..." alt="" /><a href="#">test 1</a></li>
   <li><img src="..." alt="" /><a href="#">test 2</a></li>
   <li><img src="..." alt="" /><a href="#">test 2</a></li>
</ul>


ul#list-cats li {border:1px solid red;}
ul#list-cats li li {border:1px solid cyan;}
```

This is from the W3C documentation:

> `E + F` Matches any F element immediately preceded by a sibling element E.

Why don’t all the other `<li>` tags get a cyan border?

PS: I know this can be done using the `:first-child` selector, but I want to figure this problem out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are not using the `+` selector at all.

I suppose you wanted to write

```
ul#list-cats li + li {border:1px solid cyan;} 
/*             ^^^ */
```

which would give a cyan border to all `li`s except the first one (which is not preceded by a `li` since it is the first).

Comment: yes, i forgot the + when typing.. .but it doesnt work even with the  forgotten +

Comment: @Marco Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/73x4k/ Which browser doesn' it work in? (edit: forgot to save before linking)

Comment: Chrome 15.0.874 firefox 7.0.1

Comment: @Marco sorry gave the wrong link on my comment, I see first one with red border and the rest with cyan after pasting in your code and adding the `+`

Comment: ok! i apologize... i does work indeed! i've checked the php that generates the list and realize that the '<ul>' was inside the 'while' loop ... my mistake... again, sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 2):

Your CSS selects all `li` tags which are descendants of a `li` tag:

```
ul#list-cats li li {border:1px solid cyan;}
```

You have no nested `li` tags, so that selector won't find any elements.

Did you mean to include a `+` in there?

Comment: yes, i ment to include a + in the example, wich i forgot... but even with the +, i dont get the expected results